# How to simulate user input when writing bash script on a shell device

Tags: bash, shell, input, adb

I am writing a script to automate a large number of steps needed for provisioning an android device. However, I am having a trouble with one particular step. There is a command that I have to run on an android device via *adb shell "...command..."*. The problem is that this command then requires an input from the keyboard, which is always "1".

I tried this with the *xdotool*, like this: *adb shell "...command"..."* ; xdotool 1*. However, this does not work because the second command will execute only after the first one is finished, but the first one cannot be finished without an input. Also, I think this still wouldn't work because *xdtool 1* would input 1 in the current terminal, and not in the *adb shell* one. And I can't use adb shell "xdotool 1", because the android device does not have *xdotool*. I read about *expect* scripts as well, but was unable to implement them in this situation. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at `expect`

Comment: Does `adb shell "...command..." <<<"1"` (or `echo 1 | adb shell "...command..."`) do it?

Comment: @GordonDavisson the first suggestion with <<< works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this works:

```
adb shell "...command..." <<< "1"
```